# SonarQube: weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key issue with SSL

Tags: ssl, sonarqube, diffie-hellman

How do we by pass this issue with SonarQube server v5.1 and firefox? Chrome & IE are working fine but firefox is not allowing to access the server in https mode. I looked at https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html but I am not sure what server SonarQube uses and how to implement fix for this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user wants to enable (or restrict) access to a SonarQube instance over HTTPS, the recommended way is to put it behind another WebServer she configures at will.

So, the way to go here, is to add an Apache, Nginx or whatever in front of the SQ instance and configure it according to the recommendations in the [link](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html) you provided and generate a "safe" server certificate.

Comment: SonarQube runs on a embedded tomcat server, right? In that case how can I add apache in front of SonarQube? Is there a wiki page with instructions for this type of scenario?

Comment: How to setup a Apache server to proxy access to a Tomcat server is not specific to SonarQube at all. Try googling "apache proxy to tomcat" for example and you will fine lots of resources on the matter

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the problem by setting up reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the following property in sonar.properties file.

sonar.web.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA